# Copiar un archivo grande usando FileSystem.CopyFile en VBscript

Tags: ajax, vbscript, filesystem

Utilizo `FileSystem.CopyFile` para copiar un archivo de 1GB a otro directorio.

Mientras tanto, otro programa, necesita determinar que el archivo ya ha sido completamente copiado para realizar su labor.

¿Cómo puedo determinar que ya el archivo ha sido copiado? Es decir, cómo saber que la copia se ha realizado completamente.

¿Podría ser utilizando el atributo `Size` del archivo?

Comment: Jorge no está claro porqué la etiqueta `ajax`. ¿Cuál es el código de lo que ya tienes hecho?

Comment: if fso.FolderExists (CaminoCarpeta & "\" & Usuariosisop) then
    ' response.Write "El folder existe" & CaminoCarpeta & "\" & Session ("Usuariosisop")
    fso.DeleteFile CaminoCarpeta & "\" & Usuariosisop & "\*.*", True  
 else
    fso.CreateFolder CaminoCarpeta & "\" & Usuariosisop
 end if
    
    archivoOrig = caminoCarpeta + "\arc_" & idArchDig & "." & extensionArchivo
    archivoDest = caminoCarpeta + "\" & usuarioSisop & "\" & Descripcion + "." & extensionArchivo
    f.WriteLine(archivoOrig)
    f.WriteLine(archivoDest)
    fso.CopyFile archivoOrig, archivoDest

Comment: Lo siento pero no se como dar formato al código para que sea más fácil de leer.

Comment: La etiqueta AJAX la utilizo porque después de resolver el problema, voy a utilizar la solución en un ambiente con AJAX. Por ahora se puede ignorar.

Comment: @JorgeCabrera edita tu pregunta y copia ahí el codigo. Dentro del editor podrás darle el formato de código

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Stackoverflow Jorge.

No hay forma *nativa* de hacerlo pero si hay trucos que pudieran ayudarnos.

Un ejemplo seria haciendo que el programa que espera a que el archivo termine este siempre preguntando si existe un archivo llamado `copy.done` cada 3 segundos en la ruta donde se esta copiando el archivo de 1GB. Si el archivo existe pues entonces es porque ya se termino de copiar y entonces procede a borrar el archivo `copy.done`. Claro, eso quiere decir que el software que esta copiando cree el archivo en el directorio de destino una vez terminado el proceso copia.